# Ubuntu 17.10, Kernel 4.13.x doesn't recognize hard drive that 4.10.x does

Tags: kernel, mount, disk, 17.10

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 (kernel 4.13.x) my system won't recognize one of my hard drives.  If I comment that disk out of /etc/fstab it boots as expected (but this is problematic as this particular disk is my home directory).

If I instead boot with kernel 4.10.x, everything works perfectly fine (and fsck on that same disk comes back clean).

The error logs from boot say:

```
systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\[uuid-related-text].device: Job dev-disk-by\uuid-related-text].device/start timed out.
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\[uuid-related-text].device
```

Trying to mount later (or doing anything that accesses the drive) simply hangs the process (and I'm not sure where to check for logs on that).

How do I proceed to troubleshooting why this disk is inaccessible on the 4.13.x kernel?

### Update 1

The drive is connected via SATA.

Running `sudo blkid` doesn't even list the drive when booted using 4.13.x kernel (whereas it's listed fine when using 4.10.x kernel).

Here is my fstab, but please keep in mind that I have to comment out the second drive in order to boot into 4.13.x.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=7F39-483A  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=673f3491-fbbf-4581-8a1e-336c18018915       /home/user      ext2    defaults        0       1
```

The output of the following commands in 4.10.x kernel vs 4.13.x kernel.

```
$ uname -a
Linux Machine 4.10.0-32201708161632-generic #0+mediatree+hauppauge-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 17 00:27:10 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="673f3491-fbbf-4581-8a1e-336c18018915" TYPE="ext2" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="e1d29699-f81d-4a28-bcac-befddbf6725c"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="7F39-483A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="38b9ba9e-a5b2-43ae-8cf6-2c1d8aa133fc"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="qcIT7f-qcrE-Ej7m-aANa-I1UD-5TvA-fUZZPM" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="736726e8-5263-4e33-b332-c8c2e5281d1e"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root: UUID="e121a14f-6885-4e5b-8951-593664b7838a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1: UUID="d6a0a7e9-78fa-4894-a9ab-8a71cd6e572a" TYPE="swap"

$ uname -a
Linux Machine 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="7F39-483A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="38b9ba9e-a5b2-43ae-8cf6-2c1d8aa133fc"
/dev/sda2: UUID="qcIT7f-qcrE-Ej7m-aANa-I1UD-5TvA-fUZZPM" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="736726e8-5263-4e33-b332-c8c2e5281d1e"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root: UUID="e121a14f-6885-4e5b-8951-593664b7838a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1: UUID="d6a0a7e9-78fa-4894-a9ab-8a71cd6e572a" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: Do a `sudo blkid` and make sure that the UUIDs match what you have in `/etc/fstab` for your /home partition.

Comment: It does.  I was previously addressing it via `/dev/sda1` and switched it to UUID while trying to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: FWIW, `sudo blkid` doesn't even list the drive when I've booted into the 4.13.x kernel instead of the 4.10.x kernel.

Comment: How is this drive/partition (please clarify which) connected to the system? SATA? USB? Something else? Does 4.13 see other partitions on the same drive? Can you `fsck -f /dev/sda1`? Edit your question to include the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and a screenshot of `gparted` and I'll take a look. Make sure to start comments to me with `@heynnema`, or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema edits added as requested.  I can run `fsck -f /dev/sda1` when booted into the 4.10.x kernel, however as you can see from the output of `blkid`, under the 4.13.x kernel it wouldn't do what we hope as the drive isn't even present.  I don't have GUI access to provide `gparted`, sorry.

Comment: Is this a server installation, or 17.10 gnome on wayland? I ask because you indicate no GUI for gparted. Your /etc/fstab shows `/home/user` as an **ext2** partition, but blkid shows it as a **LVM2** partition. Which is it? Somehow it looks wrong.

Comment: You should [report the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect) on Launchpad. A cursory Google search shows that you are not alone; on the [Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230483) the common suggestion is to try booting with `intel_iommu=off`.

Comment: @heynnema: 17.10 Gnome, I am just not physically in the same location as the machine and VNC stopped working with the upgrade too.

Doesn't `TYPE="ext2"` on the drive mean it's *ext2*?  Why do you believe it's *LVM2*?  My other drive (that is listed as `sdb` on 4.10.x and `sda` on 4.13.x) is *LVM2*, but I don't believe the one having trouble is.

@AlexP Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @chucksense Oh, I see my confusion... when /dev/sda1disappears in 4.13, it renames /dev/sdb1 and b2 to a1 and a2. I guess that I'm still concerned about /dev/sda1 being ext2. Maybe 4.13 no longer supports ext2? Why ext2 instead of ext4?

Comment: That is a great question and I don't have an answer (probably just a mistake on my part).  Next tactic I'm going to try is reformat to ext4 and see if it helps.

Comment: @heynnema Reformatting the drive to `ext4` made no difference.  The system simply does not "see" the drive when using the 4.13.x kernel (whereas it works fine it 4.10.x).

Comment: @chucksense thanks for the update! I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Seems there may be a bug in the kernel that impacts my system/drive: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1730746